# input validation and how to improve it

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

I have put together a function for input validation (currently without the use of try/except blocks).

It works but the error correction brings about odd behaviour...i.e once the error is corrected by the user they have to press the calculate button twice for it to fire correctly?

```
def validation(self):

    partval = self.partDiaText.text()
    partlentext = self.partLenText.text()
    matdia = self.matDiaText.text()

    if partval.isalpha():
        self.error_label.setText("The part diameter must be a number!")
        self.partDiaText.setText("")

    elif partval == 0:
        self.error_label.setText("The part diameter must be greater than zero!")

    elif partlentext.isalpha():
        self.partLenText.setText("")
        self.error_label.setText("The part length must be a number!")

    elif partlentext == 0:
        self.error_label.setText("The part length must be greater than zero!")

    elif matdia.isalpha():
        self.matDiaText.setText("")
        self.error_label.setText("The material diameter must be a number!")

    elif matdia == 0:
        self.error_label.setText("The material diameter must be greater than zero!")


    else:
        self.error_label.clear()
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.reset_output)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.calc_machining)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.calc_times)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.calc_qtyVar)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.work_centre)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.material_code)
```

EDIT: even if there is no error i still have to press pushbutton_2 twice to get the clicked.connects to fire. If i take all of the clicked.connects out of the validation function and put them in the main init function it fires correctly but without any vaildation on the inputs.

Comment: Can you explain your problem more? Are you sure this odd behavior is because of the `validation` method?
Also, for better user experience, aggregate the error messages into one. In your method, if the user has multiple errors, they will have to try several times.

Comment: I don't want else to fire if any of the if/elif statements are true. I want to reset the inputs of the offending form elements and offer helpful feedback on what the problems are via a label. There is nothing going on in my program until it has passed through validation function. I had some success using a while true loop but i couldnt get a try except block to work.

Comment: My guess is that, as hinted by noidsirius, the first time you clic, validation is executed and connects the clic-to-slots. The 2nd time the slots are indeed executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that, as hinted by @noidsirius, the first time you clic, validation is executed and connects the clic-to-slots. The 2nd time the slots are indeed executed.

If this guess is correct, a solution could be:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.validate_and_run_if_ok)
    # etc.

def validate_and_run_if_ok(self):

    partval = self.partDiaText.text()
    partlentext = self.partLenText.text()
    matdia = self.matDiaText.text()

    if partval.isalpha():
        self.error_label.setText("The part diameter must be a number!")
        self.partDiaText.setText("")

    elif partval == 0:
        self.error_label.setText("The part diameter must be greater than zero!")

    elif partlentext.isalpha():
        self.partLenText.setText("")
        self.error_label.setText("The part length must be a number!")

    elif partlentext == 0:
        self.error_label.setText("The part length must be greater than zero!")

    elif matdia.isalpha():
        self.matDiaText.setText("")
        self.error_label.setText("The material diameter must be a number!")

    elif matdia == 0:
        self.error_label.setText("The material diameter must be greater than zero!")


    else:
        self.error_label.clear()
        self.reset_output()
        self.calc_machining()
        self.calc_times()
        self.calc_qtyVar()
        self.work_centre()
        self.material_code()
```

(The only modif are the else block, and an added line to **init**)